# Using d3.js, mongoose, mongoDB, express properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, d3.js, mongoose

I'm really new to node.js and I've been reading a lot of tutorials and documentation on node.js, mongoose, mongoDB, Express, etc and I feel I'm still not getting something.

I want to make a website where data is generated by querying mongoDB and then results are returned to browser where it is visualized in d3.js.

I currently have a graph in d3 as a separate JS file (jdriver.js) called in the head of my jade file. My jdriver.js file is very self-contained in that it generates all the buttons, filters, sliders, etc.). However I'm not sure how I could go about, say if I want to apply a filter -> query mongodb -> have mongodb return a JSON data file -> redraws with new data.

And then how to fit all of that within the framework provided by Express? 
Would someone be as kind to either point me to some sources or help me out?

Thanks so much.

Comment: could be relevant -- http://paulcrickard.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/d3-js-and-mongodb/